# Searchform put automatically the user in the search

Tags: php, search

In a wordpress website, I have links to open a search module.
When I click onto it, it opens a searchform with a placeholder.
Here is the php code of the searchform :

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '' ) ); ?>/">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Search a movie', 'the-league' ); ?>" onfocus='if (this.value == "<?php esc_html_e( '', 'the-league' ); ?>") { this.value = ""; }' onblur='if (this.value == "") { this.value = "<?php esc_html_e( '', 'the-league' ); ?>"; }' />
    <input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

But users have to click a second time, in order to actually search. Which is annoying and useless.

Any idea of what I could do so that the users are actually in the searchbox and can just start typing without having to click again?

Best,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use focus method to set the focus directly on the element after load.

```
document.getElementById("mytext").focus();
```

In your case the id is 's'

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

With the following code :  
`document.getElementById("s").focus();`  

The placeholder is deleted, but the focus doesnt go directly on the searchmodule  

If it can help, here is my website :  
https://club-stephenking.fr/biographie-de-stephen-king  


Thanks !